# Display List<dynamic> with Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor, expando

I am using list of dynamic (anonymous objects) in a Razor view and display it.

Controller Code :

```
var res = (from c in _context.DM_Suivi_Us_Servis
                       group c by new { c.designation_magasin,c.designation_uf} into g
                       select new
                       {
                           g.Key.designation_magasin,
                           g.Key.designation_uf,
                           sum = g.Sum(c => c.nbr_us_servis),
                       }).ToList();

return View(res);
```

View Page (Razor view):

```
@model IEnumerable<dynamic>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.ToString()</td>
    </tr>
}
```

displays this result:

```
{ designation_magasin = CO3, designation_uf = NRG, sum = 65 }
{ designation_magasin = INC, designation_uf = NRG, sum = 0 } etc..
```

But when I try to display each item attribute:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.sum</td>
        <td>@item.designation_uf</td>
        <td>@item.designation_magasin</td>
    </tr>
}
```

I receive this following error

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: Create a view model with those 3 properties and project your query into a collection of the view model and return the view model to the view

Comment: Just create a View Model, don't be lazy

Comment: Hi , thanks for you answer i have already tried to create a new ViewModel , but i will use this methode often with different ViewModel so i think it's better to use an Anonymose object .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new view model :

```
public class YourName
{
    public string DesignationMagasin { get; set; }
    public string DesignationUf { get; set; }
    public int SumServis { get; set; }
}
```

And use projection

```
var res = (from c in _context.DM_Suivi_Us_Servis
            group c by new { c.designation_magasin, c.designation_uf } into g
            select new YourName
            {
                DesignationMagasin= g.Key.designation_magasin,
                DesignationUf= g.Key.designation_uf,
                SumServis= g.Sum(c => c.nbr_us_servis),
            }).ToList();
```

in view add `@model List<YourName>`

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381412(v=vs.108).aspx) you find  more about MVC.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for you answer it's working 100% but i will be using a lot of ViewModels so it's better to use Anonymose Type ?